# pass an array of objects from one method to another in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, loops, for-loop

i want to pass an array of objects i have stored in one for loop to a second for loop in another method to display the contents. e.g:

```
public static Student[] add()
for(int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter student name ");
            studentName = EasyIn.getString();
            System.out.print("Enter student Id ");
            studentId = EasyIn.getString();
            System.out.print("Enter mark ");
            studentMark = EasyIn.getInt();
            studentArray[i] = new Student(); //create object
            tempObject = new Student(studentName,studentId,studentMark);
            place = findPlace(studentArray,studentName, noOfElements);
            noOfElements = addOne(studentArray, place, tempObject, noOfElements);   
        }
```

into here

```
public static void displayAll()
{
Student[] anotherArray = add();
    for(int i = 0; i < anotherArray.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(anotherArray[i].toString());
    }   
}
```

to call it in a menu here:

```
                        case '3': System.out.println("List All");
                                  displayAll();
                                  EasyIn.pause();
```

when i press 3 on the menu it just calls the add method again but when i add in the values into the array again then it displays the array. i just want to display the array only

Comment: Your code won't compile.
In your `add()` method you should put curly brackets `{` and `}`, and it should `return` somethinf of `Student[]` type.

Comment: The question is unclear, would you clarify the behavior that you don't want? It is that each time you call `add()` you are reconstructing the array and you only want this to happen once?

Comment: they are just a sample of the code i have shown, shall i paste all the code i have done and show you?

Comment: @ john B each time i call the display method it recontructs the array and then displays it. i just want to display it.

Comment: If `add()` reconstructs the array, and you call `add()` at the begining of `displayAll()` (inside it), every time you call `displayAll()`, you'll be reconstructing the array.

Try @mcfinnigan or @Rahul Borkar solutions.

Comment: http://www.multiupload.nl/SVS1GMOXE2

http://www.multiupload.nl/U9T1IASH8E

http://www.multiupload.nl/HL24I4O5U1

these are my project files, download them and put in the same folder and compile project2 and it should run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to others

```
public void displayAll(Student... students) {    
    for(Student student:students)
        System.out.print(student+" "); // so there is space between the toString
    System.out.println();
}
```

or

```
public void displayAll(Student... students) {    
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(students));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change displayAll() to take the array as a parameter:

```
public void displayAll(Student[] students) {
  ...
}
```

and call it as follows:

```
Student [] students = add();

...

case '3': System.out.println("List All");
    displayAll(students);
    EasyIn.pause();
```

Comment: well it works to a certain degree, each time it calls the 
    Student [] students = add();
it calls the add() method for some strange reason

Answer (score 1):

You can change your displayAll method definition to

```
public static void displayAll(Student[] anotherArray)
{    
    for(int i = 0; i < anotherArray.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(anotherArray[i].toString());
    }   
}
```

and then call add method from wherever you want to call before switch case and call displayAll method with student[] as parameter.